# mysql install init failure on centos7

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install Mysql Community Server version5.6.40 on my Centos7 VM.

During the installation i have met below problems:

1)

```
[root@Mysql_Server scripts]# ./mysql_install_db.sh --user=mysql --basedir=/application/mysql --datadir=/application/mysql/data
-bash: ./mysql_install_db.sh: Permission denied

[root@Mysql_Server support-files]# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
-bash: /etc/init.d/mysqld: Permission denied
```

i have use chmod a+x filename to assign the execute rights but i just want to know why those files lacks of execution rights. //i download the mysql installation tar file and extract with root privilege

2)while i was running the mysql_install_db.sh

```
[root@Mysql_Server scripts]# ./mysql_install_db.sh --user=mysql --basedir=/application/mysql --datadir=/application/mysql/data

FATAL ERROR: Could not find my_print_defaults

The following directories were searched:

    /application/mysql/bin
    /application/mysql/extra

If you compiled from source, you need to run 'make install' to
copy the software into the correct location ready for operation.

If you are using a binary release, you must either be at the top
level of the extracted archive, or pass the --basedir option
pointing to that location.
```

i tried follow steps to find out what the possible reason for causing this issue:

```
find / my_print_defaults 

find: ‘my_print_defaults’: No such file or directory
```

and

```
ls /application/mysql/


[root@Mysql_Server scripts]# ls /application/mysql/
BUILD            dbug                 libmysqld    README      support-files
client           Docs                 libservices  regex       tests
cmake            Doxyfile-perfschema  man          scripts     unittest
CMakeLists.txt   extra                mysql-test   sql         VERSION
cmd-line-utils   include              mysys        sql-bench   vio
config.h.cmake   INSTALL              mysys_ssl    sql-common  win
configure.cmake  libevent             packaging    storage     zlib
COPYING          libmysql             plugin       strings
```

no bin and extra directory were created.

so i was wondering if it was caused by lacking of gcc gcc-c++ because my centos7 installation chose minimal install.

or maybe it was caused by lacking of execution rights result the shell files did run correctly.

attached:below whole operations for better trouble shooting

```
[root@Mysql_Server ~]# yum install wget -y      
[root@Mysql_Server ~]# wget https://cdn.mysql.com/archives/mysql-5.6/mysql-5.6.40.tar.gz  
[root@Mysql_Server ~]# tar -xf mysql-5.6.40.tar.gz 
[root@Mysql_Server ~]# mkdir /application   
[root@Mysql_Server ~]# mv mysql-5.6.40 /application/    
[root@Mysql_Server ~]# ln -s /application/mysql-5.6.40/ /application/mysql      
[root@Mysql_Server ~]# cd /application/mysql/support-files/ 
[root@Mysql_Server support-files]# cp my-default.cnf.sh /etc/my.cnf         
[root@Mysql_Server support-files]# cp mysql.server.sh /etc/init.d/mysqld              
[root@Mysql_Server support-files]# cd /application/mysql/scripts/       
[root@Mysql_Server scripts]# useradd mysql -s /sbin/nologin -M      
[root@Mysql_Server scripts]# chmod a+x mysql_install_db.sh
[root@Mysql_Server scripts]# ./mysql_install_db.sh --user=mysql --basedir=/application/mysql --datadir=/application/mysql/data
```

Comment: You are running the unconfigured `mysql_install_db`. You need to build MySQL as this populated the mysql_install_db.sh with specific paths. You can't just chmod +x and run it. Either download the binary package, or install the becessary dependencies and build it.

Comment: can you give me more specific instructions if it is possible

Comment: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/ - pick "Linux Generic or "Red Hat Enterprise Linux"

Comment: thanks danblack, i think i am using the source code without encoding and packaging .i am know going to download one that encoded. i will add cmmts and chose your answer later.

Answer (score 0):

It is a fatal mistake by misunderstanding between the source code and binary package.

Since i downloaded the source code which can not be run directly without encoding and packaging.

Thanks again for @danblack's reminds!

I've successfully run mysql_community_server on centos7 now.(using the binary package installed).

now i am going to install mysql by using the source code.